# Creating different coordinates with the same macro

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am creating a 3d image using `pgfplots`. To specify certain coordinates, I created a macro

```
\newcommand{\setpolarcoord}[4]{  % {Name}{r}{theta}{phi}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tx}{#2*sin(#3)*cos(#4)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ty}{#2*sin(#3)*sin(#4)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\tz}{#2*cos(#3)}
    \coordinate (#1) at (\tx, \ty, \tz);
}
```

In `pgfplots` I can then use this macro to specify a coordinate by its spherical coordinates:

```
\setpolarcoord{C}{1}{90}{25};
\draw [->] (0, 0, 0) -- (C);
```

When I do this multiple times inside the same `axis`-environment however, all created coordinates are the same (the last one created), probably due to the fact that i change `\tx`, `\ty` and `\tz` inside the macro, and `pgfplots` only expands when everything to be plotted is specified.

Is there a way to expand the values inside the macro, so that the individual created coordinates do not change later?

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you! Can you point me towards an explanation, why? I guess the `\temp` is the stuff I needed?

Comment: Thanks again or the explanation. It works well without `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup` as well.

Comment: I've converted the comments to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last item in the definition is not expanded on the read phase but stored with the last values of `\tx,\ty,\tz`.

To make them expanded you can change the last line to

```
\edef\temp{\noexpand\coordinate (#1) at (\tx, \ty, \tz);}\temp
```

---

Here `\edef` is expanded definition which expands the argument before the assignment. We temporarily define a macro via `\edef` and call it `\temp` but place a `\noexpand` which leaves the `\coordinate` untouched during expansion. So effectively we expand whatever expandable except `\coordinate`. Hence now we have a macro `\temp` defined as

```
\coordinate (<Name>) at (<num>,<num>,<num>);
```

But it is only defined so far. Hence we add another `\temp` at the end to execute it. To make it actually super rigorous, you write

```
\begingroup\edef\temp{\endgroup\noexpand\coordinate (#1) at (\tx, \ty, \tz);}\temp
```

such that `\temp` vanishes after execution by closing the group opened before the definition and leaving only the contents on the stream.